# What does 려나 하다 mean?

Tags: grammar

I am watching 삼진그룹 영어토익반 and I saw the following line with an ending that I had not seen before:

> 이제 일 좀 하**려나 했**더니 TL: I thought you'd finally be useful, and what?

There is 려나 보다 which could fit, but I do not think they are the same.

So what is happening here? What does 려나 하다 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common meaning of the *auxiliary* verb “하다”<sub>—I’m not talking about the ordinary verb “하다” meaning “to do”—</sub>that follows some conjugations, is “to think,” “생각하다.” When you see such “…(something) 하다,” it might, and often, mean “…(something) 생각하다,” “to think that (something).”

The ending “-려고 하나?”/“-려고 하나” or its contraction “-려나?”/“-려나” translates to “(Is it/Is he/Are you/Are they/…) about to—?”, and is used, as a *question* to ask someone, or as a *personal guess* to ask oneself.

---

> 이제 네가 일 좀 하**려(고 하)나**
>
> *“Now, **are you about to** get to work?”*

It can be either “하려나” or “하려고 하나.” It’s a personal guess, asking oneself. Note that the Korean language has lots of talking-to-self forms to express one’s thought, integrated into its grammar. (Just like Japanese, if you’re familiar with it.)

> (생각)했더니
>
> *I thought … and …*

The past form of “하다,” “했다,” and the conjunction “-더니,” “and.” The implied meaning of the “했다” is “생각했다,” “I thought.”

---

> 이제 네가 일 좀 하**려(고 하)나** **(생각)했더니**
>
> ***I was like**, “Now, **are you going to** get to work?”, and …*
>
> *I thought you’d finally be useful, and …*